# What do you call the problem with this audio from cassette tape, and how do I fix it?

Tags: audio-recording, distortion, audio-restoration, repair, tape

I have a cassette tape recording of a spoken radio interview. The first half of the recording went bad years ago. Now, whenever I play it (regardless of the tape player), it sounds something like this:

https://soundcloud.com/josh-renaud-1/interview-damaged-section/s-fXRT28ADNZ6

The damaged portion is 14 minutes long. As the recording plays, it sort of recovers gradually. Finally, at a station break, the audio finally becomes perfect again. I have about 6 minutes of good audio after the damaged 14. The audio clip I shared above is from the end of the damaged section -- [the beginning sounds much worse](https://soundcloud.com/josh-renaud-1/damaged-beginning/s-GYxG62uTRP4).

Can anyone tell me precisely what is wrong? Is it "distortion"? Did the tape get stretched or something?

And is there any way to fix the audio digitally so that the voices at least become understandable, even if the quality remains poor? If so, what filters or techniques should I use?

(I own Amadeus Pro for the Mac, but don't know much about very technical audio work)

Comment: It's called wow… though in this particular case it may be ***WOW ! ! !*** ;)

Comment: Actually, I just listened to the 2nd example. "Wow & flutter" usually come as a pair - that 2nd one is the epitome of flutter, gone mad. I really see little hope of fixing that.

Comment: "Wow and flutter". I never heard of these before. Thanks so much for helping me, I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that occurred during the original recording. Sounds very much like the tape capstan rubbers are slipping and the tape is not being kept up-to-speed during the recording.

There is only one piece of software that has any hope of fixing this, and it's "Capstan" from Celemony (makers of Melodyne). Make sure you are sitting on a good solid chair before you search for this on their website.

Comment: Sitting down, with a good strong drink in your hand ;) Capstan *might* be able to do it, but by heck you're going to need some patience. It will be a manual curve-drawing exercise. Capstan **really** likes complex music for best analysis - the less info it has to work from, the worse job it makes. A solo speaking voice is about as bad as it gets.

Comment: ...and the clip the OP posted was the good part... :-(

Comment: I just gave the first example to Capstan - it thought about it for quite a while & eventually came up with… no improvement whatsoever :\ It has nothing to track, really. [What can I say, every single movie & TV project I had lined up for the next 3 months has been cancelled or postponed… I've not a lot else to do except mess with stuff to see what happens ;)

Comment: yeah we're all in the same boat mate. Might be worth posting a Stack question in this light and see what people come up with!

Comment: We could start up the the chat room here… "Hey, whatcher doin' today?" 'Pickin' ma toenails & watching daytime TV." "Yup, me too…" What **should** you have been doing? I had the next 3 months booked on the new H.Potter, Fab Beasts 3… They even cancelled Eastenders, which is my usual bread & butter :\ [& I just this minute found I **will** get paid for today's cancellation, so Yay!

Comment: I just heard from my agent - there are no productions they are aware of that are still running in the UK. [Probably some small indies, but nothing of any note].

Comment: Off 2 bed now, but will set up a zoom or google hangout thing we can just use. beats dredging up the usual shows on netflix...

Comment: @Tetsujin Would Capstan have a better chance with the full 14 mins to analyze, or probably not?

Comment: @Mark, I could be wrong, but I seem to remember this tape working when I originally received it (20 years ago). Is it possible the "wow and flutter" was caused by damage or mechanical problem in the cassette later?

Comment: It's possible. If the pinch roller/capstan was slipping or meeting too much resistance during the initial recording, the pitch on correct playback would go 'chipmunk'. As it goes more 'beelzebub' then it may be the current tape which is sticking on playback. Quick if not particular scientific 'fix' is to fast wind it from end to end a few times, see if it frees up. If that kind of works but not perfectly you could transfer the tape into a new case [or find a pro to do it].